Insetting individual faces problem: they are not the same size
I'm having a little issue when insetting faces individually to this object.

As you can see the faces on the center end up being smaller while the ones on the sides are wider, you can notice it better when I delete them.

I want all of them to be the same size so how can I fix this?

Have you applied the scale to the object?

https://i.sstatic.net/4aqOWdZL.png I've make some mesh like you did, but I have no issues at all, I try to modify the mesh with proportional editing and scale it randomly but it still no issue. Send me the project file I want to look at it if you would.

Just applied the scale and it worked, so that was the problem... thanks a lot
